# outlook addin notification message

Tags: node.js, api, events, outlook-addin, office-js

I would like to develop a simple outlook addin which displays confirmation message before sending email. 
For some reason, it only displays the default error message says "The addin xxx is blokcing this email from being sent". 
Also even I allow the event to be completed, it doesn't allow me to send.

manifest.xml

```html
  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>

  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
  </Rule>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <!-- On Send requires VersionOverridesV1_1 -->
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Description resid="residAppDescription" />
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <!-- The functionfile and function name to call on message send.  -->
            <!-- In this particular case the function calculateCostAndWarn will be called within the JavaScript code referenced in residUILessFunctionFileUrl. -->
            <FunctionFile resid="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" />
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
              <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="calculateCostAndWarn" />
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Urls>
          <!-- The JavaScript code is hosted on a secure and trusted web server. -->
          <bt:Url id="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html" ></bt:Url>
        </bt:Urls>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
```

index.js

```js
var mailboxItem;

Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    mailboxItem = Office.context.mailbox.item;
}

// Entry point for add-in before send is allowed.
function calculateCostAndWarn(event) {
 mailboxItem.notificationMessages.addAsync("information", {
     type: "informationalMessage",
     message : "The add-in processed this message.",
     icon : "iconid",
     persistent: false
 });
 event.completed({ allowEvent: true });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try logging some useful information to console whenever  calculateCostAndWarn() is called? I just wanted to rule out a possibility, where the send operations is blocked because the add-in is not loaded properly/ loaded with some error.

Comment: i put console.log("initialize"); in Office.initialize, and console.log("event caught"); in calculateCostAndWarn. In Chrome console, it shows "initialize", but not "event caught"

Comment: silly mistake, the reference to index.js in the index.html is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

silly mistake, the reference to index.js in the index.html is wrong